# How to Iterate two arrays consecutively?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, for-loop

I have two Double arrays:

```
double[] LatArr = {28.5700,28.4700,28.29};
double[] LonArr = {77.3200,77.0300,77.62};
```

And my loop structure looks like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                {
                    Double lat1;
                    Double lon1;
                    Double lat2;
                    Double lon2;
                    lat1 = LatArr[i];
                    lon1 = LonArr[j];
                    //System.out.println(LatLon[i][j]);
                    /*System.out.println("<< BREAK >>");
                    System.out.println(lat1);
                    System.out.println(lon1);
                    */
                    lat2=lat1;
                    //lat1 = null;
                    lon2=lon1;
                    //lon1 = null;
                    i++;

                    if(lat1!=null){
                    GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lon1 * 1E6)); //
                    GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lon2 * 1E6)); //
                    System.out.println("<< LAT1 >>");
                    System.out.println(lat1);
                    System.out.println(lon1);
                    System.out.println("<< LAT2 >>");
                    System.out.println(lat2);
                    System.out.println(lon2);

                    Point p11 = new Point();
                    Point p22 = new Point();

                    Path mypath = new Path();
                    projection.toPixels(gp1, p11);
                    projection.toPixels(gp2, p22);
                    mypath.moveTo(p22.x, p22.y);// *
                    mypath.lineTo(p11.x, p11.y);// *

                    canvas.drawPath(mypath, mPaint);
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I am trying to do is to fetch the item LatArr[0] and LonArr[0] consecutively. 
So that I can have the LatArr[0] in lat1 and LonArr[0] in lon1. Also the LatArr[1] should be in lat2 and LonArr[1] in lon2.
But this code fetches LatArr[0]..[1].. and LonArr[0]..[1].. twice. Every element is printed twice?
Anyone please correct me, I am loosing all hope to follow this approach to draw multiple points on a map. In all this code will map the two geo points one after the another (each geopoint has latitude & longitude which are being fed from the two arrays)
Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: you need only one loop, and you need to realize that if you try to access items at the *same* index, using a different index (i!=j) is not likely to work.

Comment: Why not use a single array of GeoPoints?

Comment: @nkr No. That's why I have this loop in place. Now see, these two arrays will be populated at runtime from a database. So, I wouldn't know how many items will these arrays will contain. But both will ahve same nos. of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand, why you have two loops, try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++)
        {

                Double lat1;
                Double lon1;
                Double lat2;
                Double lon2;
                lat1 = LatArr[i];
                lon1 = LonArr[i];

                /*System.out.println("<< BREAK >>");
                System.out.println(lat1);
                System.out.println(lon1);
                */
                lat2=latArr[i+1];
                //lat1 = null;
                lon2=lonArr[i+1];
                //lon1 = null;


                if(lat1!=null){
                GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lon1 * 1E6)); //
                GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lon2 * 1E6)); //
                System.out.println("<< LAT1 >>");
                System.out.println(lat1);
                System.out.println(lon1);
                System.out.println("<< LAT2 >>");
                System.out.println(lat2);
                System.out.println(lon2);

                Point p11 = new Point();
                Point p22 = new Point();

                Path mypath = new Path();
                projection.toPixels(gp1, p11);
                projection.toPixels(gp2, p22);
                mypath.moveTo(p22.x, p22.y);// *
                mypath.lineTo(p11.x, p11.y);// *

                canvas.drawPath(mypath, mPaint);
                }

        }
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks :) oh wait..I din't changing the updated code.

Comment: Didn't you forget to set iteration bound to count-1 ?

Comment: With the code having "i<count-1" & uncommented "i++" the output is something different. Look, now to map each of these co ordinates it need to be something like this: lat1-lon1 (origin) and lat2-lon2 (dest) and then again lat2-lon2 (new origin) and lat3-lon3 pair (new dest) And this keeps going on.. for n no. of elements. I was able to achieve this by the previous code in which still "i<count;" and "i++" was commented out. But in this case I am getting a arrayoutofbounds ex.

Comment: Thanks now it worked flawlessly :) Just comment the "i++;" (below "lon2=lonArr[i+1];") and it works as expected without any exception(s). LOL it was simple than I expected..I just got boggled down within arrays. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, I just forgot to remove that i++, when writing that answer, sorry about that. Glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

If both the arrays are of same length, then use only one loop, instead of two loops, so change your code as follows:

```
for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                    {
                        Double lat1;
                        Double lon1;
                        Double lat2;
                        Double lon2;
                        lat1 = LatArr[j];
                        lon1 = LonArr[j];
                        lat2=lat1;
                        //lat1 = null;
                        lon2=lon1;
                        //lon1 = null;
                       if(lat1!=null){
                        GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lon1 * 1E6)); //
                        GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lon2 * 1E6)); //
                        System.out.println("<< LAT1 >>");
                        System.out.println(lat1);
                        System.out.println(lon1);
                        System.out.println("<< LAT2 >>");
                        System.out.println(lat2);
                        System.out.println(lon2);

                        Point p11 = new Point();
                        Point p22 = new Point();

                        Path mypath = new Path();
                        projection.toPixels(gp1, p11);
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, p22);
                        mypath.moveTo(p22.x, p22.y);// *
                        mypath.lineTo(p11.x, p11.y);// *

                        canvas.drawPath(mypath, mPaint);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yes. that's actually quite near to my required output. Thanks for replying jeet :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the same index every time so that you get the same index elements from both array.

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
  Double lat1;
  Double lon1;
  Double lat2;
  Double lon2;
  lat1 = LatArr[i];//  i th element from lat arr
  lon1 = LonArr[i];// i th element from lon arr
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes using iterating single index did the trick.